# Histogram in N dimensions with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

I'm trying to generate two 2D histograms using [numpy.histogramdd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) (I'm aware of histogram2d, but I need this one for scalability to N dimensions eventually)

Both histograms should use the same range, so I define it before obtaining them.

The issue is that I can't get my code to work, I get either a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` or a `ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32` error using different configurations.

Here's the MWE:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_data(N):
    return np.random.uniform(low=1., high=2000., size=(N,))

# Some random 2D data.
N = 100
P = [rand_data(N), rand_data(N)]
Q = [rand_data(N), rand_data(N)]

# Number of bins.
b = np.sqrt(len(P[0])) * 2

# Max and min values for x and y
x_min = np.sort(np.minimum(P[0], Q[0]))[0]
x_max = np.sort(np.minimum(P[0], Q[0]))[-1]
y_min = np.sort(np.minimum(P[1], Q[1]))[0]
y_max = np.sort(np.minimum(P[1], Q[1]))[-1]
# Range for the histograms.
rang = [np.linspace(x_min, x_max, b), np.linspace(y_min, y_max, b)]

# Histograms
d_1 = np.histogramdd(zip(*[P[0], P[1]]), range=rang)[0]
d_2 = np.histogramdd(zip(*[Q[0], Q[1]]), range=rang)[0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering why you are constructing those tuples for the histogrammdd input in the first place. This is what the docs say about the input: `It must be an (N,D) array or data that can be converted to such.` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html

Comment: @cel this is a part of a much larger code and both `P` and `Q` are defined as lists with two elements each because that's how they are given to this function. I've read the docs and checked that the shapes of the input arrays (`zip(*[P[0], P[1]])` and the same for `Q`) are `(100, 2) (100, 2)`. Why is this not correct?

Comment: Converting into a list of tuples simply does not work for me. Converting to a numpy array before invoking `histogramdd` however does work.
Second thing is, your range code. Could it be that you are mixing up the `bins` and `range` arguments?

Comment: _Converting to a numpy array before invoking histogramdd however does work_, would you care to show an example of how this works for you? I'm not confusing bins and range, I need both histograms to be calculated in the same range. What makes you think I've confused them?

Comment: Just create a numpy array from your zipped expression:
in python3 it would be `samples1 = np.array(list(*[P[0], P[1]]))`. Then you can use `hist, edges = histogramdd(samples1)`. It appears to me that you are passing the edges of the bins to the range argument. If you want to do that, those edges obviously have to be passed to the `bins` parameter, as the documentation suggests.

Comment: It should be `samples1 = np.array(list(zip(*[P[0], P[1]])))`

Comment: Ugh you are absolutely correct, sorry about that. Would you mind posting your comments as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for you. There are two issues: The edges of your bins are passed to the `bins` argument, not to the `range` argument. Besides, passing a list of tuples does not seem to work. If you convert those tuples to a numpy array and pass the array it should work as expected.

This code works for me:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_data(N):
    return np.random.uniform(low=1., high=2000., size=(N,))

# Some random 2D data.
N = 100
P = [rand_data(N), rand_data(N)]
Q = [rand_data(N), rand_data(N)]

# Number of bins.
b = np.sqrt(len(P[0])) * 2

# Max and min values for x and y
x_min = np.sort(np.minimum(P[0], Q[0]))[0]
x_max = np.sort(np.minimum(P[0], Q[0]))[-1]
y_min = np.sort(np.minimum(P[1], Q[1]))[0]
y_max = np.sort(np.minimum(P[1], Q[1]))[-1]
# Range for the histograms.
rang = [np.linspace(x_min, x_max, b), np.linspace(y_min, y_max, b)]

# Histograms
sample1 = np.array(list(zip(*[P[0], P[1]])))
sample2 = np.array(list(zip(*[Q[0], Q[1]])))
d_1 = np.histogramdd(sample1, bins=rang)[0]
d_2 = np.histogramdd(sample2, bins=rang)[0]
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `list()` around `zip()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true for python2.x. In python3.x `zip` returns a generator object instead of a list. That's why I used the explicit conversion to `list`